# Why doesn't this simple PHP return a response?

Tags: php, ajax

This is the first php program I've written. My Ajax requests look alright and I'm getting status 200 OK but not getting any response.

```
<?php

class Employee{
    private $fn;
    private $ln;
    private $dpt;
    private $ID;
}

function newEmployee(){
    $employee = new Employee();
    $fn = $_POST['firstname'];
    $ln = $_POST['lastname'];
    $dpt = $_POST['department'];
    $id = sprintf('%08d', $GLOBALS['$ID']);
    $GLOBALS['$ID'] = $GLOBALS['$ID'] + 1;

    echo "First Name: $employee\nLast Name: $ln\nDepartment: $dpt\nID: $id";

    $employee -> fn = $_POST['firstname'];
    $employee -> ln = $_POST['lastname'];
    $employee -> dpt = $_POST['department'];

    $GLOBALS['$employeeArray'][]= $employee;

    $GLOBALS['$numOfEmployees'] = $GLOBALS['$numOfEmployees'] + 1;
    $numemployees = $GLOBALS['$numOfEmployees'];

    echo "First Name: $employee\nLast Name: $ln\nDepartment: $dpt\nID: $id\nNumber of Employees: $numemployees";


}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   newEmployee();
}

$employeeArray = array();
$ID = 0;
$numOfEmployees = 0;

?>
```

Literally my first PHP program so I'm sure it's something dumb.
[image]
[image]

Comment: it's seams like you don't send a 'submit' value in your post so $_POST['submit'] is not isset

Comment: Thanks what would you suggest? Adding it to the ajax or changing that condition to something else?

Comment: to me there isn't really best practise of your ask, both should works

Comment: Why is there 2 upvotes on the top comment? You can see in the OP that he's sending a POST request...

Comment: @WillParky93 a post request without a submit key, he never enter in his function

Comment: Ok I see now, I tested his code on my machine. Even if he changes `isset($_POST['submit']])` to `isset($_POST)` he'll still get no response with his current code

Comment: As others have pointed out, judging by the screenshot, you're not sending a "submit" value in your POST request, so `isset($_POST['submit'])` will never be true, so it never runs the code that generates the output. You need to send this value from the client. I'm guessing you've maybe got a HTML button called "submit". If so, it needs to have a `name="submit"` attribute, before that value will get sent to the server. Or if you're building data for an ajax request using code, make sure you include it in that. If you're not sure, post the relevant client-side code for us to look at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code breaks because of this line:

```
 echo "First Name: $employee\nLast Name: $ln\nDepartment: $dpt\nID: $id";
```

What's happening is, you're trying to output your `$employee = new Employee();` as a string when it's an object. So PHP breaks here and will not want to continue going through the rest of your code.

Maybe you wanted it like so?

```
 echo "First Name: $fn\nLast Name: $ln\nDepartment: $dpt\nID: $id";
```

You'll also want to replace the other call of `$employee` in your second echo at the bottom of the function.

As Macbooc correctly pointed out, you're not sending `$_POST['submit']` to your form, maybe change it like so?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

->

```
if(isset($_POST))
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer to a hated question (by the haters!).

Comment: lol looking over my code now I must have been drunk when I wrote this!

Comment: then look it again in few years :)